# Copy to clipboard with disappearing message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a feature to my copy to clipboard function so that it shows "copied!" message when user clicks, with fade in effect and disappears after 5 seconds. I built the following code, it works find until it fades out the entire box! I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

```
    $(".copyto-clipboard .copyto-clipboard-text").click(function(event){
        var $tempElement = $("<input>");
        $("body").append($tempElement);
        $tempElement.val($(this).closest(".copyto-clipboard").find("span").text()).select();
        document.execCommand("Copy");
        $tempElement.remove();
        $('.copyto-clipboard').append('<span class="copied">copied!</span>').fadeIn(100).fadeOut(500);
    });
```

Comment: `.fadeOut(500)` should have been a separate line! I tried it before, it did not work, I guess I had an issue with my cache before. But I will keep this question here for reference to anyone else needs something similar.

Comment: If that's the answer to your own question, then add it as an answer (not a comment)

Comment: Instead of `$('.copyto-clipboard').append('<span class="copied">copied!</span>').fadeIn...` use `$('<span class="copied">copied!</span>').appendTo(".copyto-clipboard").fadeIn...` so that you fade in/out the element you add, not the wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are fading out the whole div, not the span you just added.
Secondly fadeout(500) is not 5 seconds. The number is in milliseconds therefore 5000 is 5 seconds.

Change your code as following to apply the fade in and fade out on the newly created span:

```
var $copiedElement = $("<span>");
$copiedElement.addClass('copied').text('copied!');
$('.copyto-clipboard').append($copiedElement);
$copiedElement.fadeIn(100);
$copiedElement.fadeOut(5000);
```

Comment: Thanks Naweed, I solved it too but appreciate your response, lets it keep for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

I made some improvements to [@NawedKhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3281014/nawed-khan) code:

```
    var $copiedElement = $("<small style='position: absolute;z-index: 10;' class='badge badge-success'>");

    if($('#idCopy').length === 0)
    {
        $copiedElement.addClass('copied').text('copied');
        $(this).append("<span id='idCopy' style='position:relative;top: -0.5rem;left: -0.2rem;'>");
        $('#idCopy').append($copiedElement);
        $('#idCopy').fadeIn(100);
        $('#idCopy').fadeOut(1000, function() { $(this).remove(); }); 
    }
```

`position: absolute;` with `relative` parent (place message anywhere you want without updating the flow of other objects on the site

`if($('#idCopy').length === 0)` (don't add a new message, if the old one still exists)

`$(this).remove();` (remove old hidden messages)